# Windows 8: Boot to non-Windows OS

Tags: windows, linux, bootloader, windows-8-preview

I previously had an install of Windows 7 on one drive, and an install of Fedora on the other hard drive. I have a partition on the second drive for GRUB, and the normal Windows bootloader partition on the first drive. I previously had it set up with EasyBCD to be able to chainload the bootloader on the second hard drive, however now with Windows 8 installed in addition to Windows 7 and Linux, it only shows the menu options for Windows (It only shows Windows 7/8 in the boot menu).

Is it still possible to boot Linux from the Windows bootloader?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling EasyBCD?

Comment: Well, it seemed that reinstalling it and then re-creating the Linux bootloader entry fixed it. The entry was already there, but it was messed up for some reason.

Comment: make sure to answer your question to tell us how you fixed it, then mark it as accepted. Glad it got figured out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by reinstalling EasyBCD, and then remaking the Linux entry. It seems to have replaced the Windows 8 bootloader with the old Windows 7 one, and it works.

Comment: Actually, it only replaces the selection menu with the old-style selection menu, but it leaves the Windows 8 bootloader in place. We're still researching the new Windows 8 boot menu, but basically, the pretty selection menu is refusing to show any non-Vista/7/8 entries.